# Change a cell colour based on cell content

Tags: javascript

I have some basic JavaScript code to scan the cells of an HTML table, and change  the background colour based on an exact value, eg if the cell value is 5, then change the color to red, and this works fine :

```
var cells = document.getElementById("test").getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
if (cells[i].innerHTML == "5") {
    cells[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }   
}
```

Typical table content :

[image]

Now, my table cells actually all contain [present/absent] figures, in the format of eg 2/0 (2 present, 0 absent), and 2/1 (2 present, 1 absent).

I am trying to highlight the cells where the figure after the '/' is greater than 0, in other words, highlight only the cells where there are absences.

I am struggling to find a way to actually do this, as I'm completely new to JavaScript. Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please show an example of the table you need to style?

Comment: Sorry, I can't get the formatting right.  I hope this shows as a table :

P1     P2     P3
3/0    2/0    5/1
3/0    6/2    4/0

...so t's the '5/1' and '6/2' that need highlighting.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, don't add code to your comments (long code in comments is virtually unreadable and anything relevant to your question should be *in* the question and obviously available to all that are trying to help you with your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can split the innerHTML by `/` and check if its bigger than 0:

```
if (cells[i].innerHTML.split("/")[1] > 0) {
    cells[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";   
}
```

Not that this will throw an error if one of your cells doesn't contain a `/`, so you should add a check for that first.

```
var splitted = cells[i].innerHTML.split("/");
if (splitted.length > 1 && splitted[1] > 0) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your HTML (at the time of writing) the best I can offer is the following:

```
// retrieve all the <td> elements within a <table>
// Use a more specific selector than 'table', such
// as a class-name or id if you have multiple <table>
// elements:
var tableCells = document.querySelectorAll('table td'),

    // converts the collection of <td> elements into
    // an Array, using Array.from():
    tableCellsArray = Array.from( tableCells ),

    // finds a sequence of one or more (+) number (\d)
    // characters following a slash (\/):
    reg = /\/\d+/,

    // 'empty' variable for use within the
    // (later) Array.prototype.forEach():
    number;

// iterating over each of the <td> elements in the
// array we created earlier using Array.prototype.forEach():
tableCellsArray.forEach(function(cell){
  // 'cell': a reference to the current <td> in the
  // array of <td> elements over which we're iterating.

  // here we use String.prototype.match()
  // to recover the matching number(s), if any,
  // from the text-content of the <td>:
  number = cell.textContent.match(reg);

  // if no match then number will be equal to null,
  // so we first test that there is a match and
  // if there is we convert the found number into
  // a base-10 number using parseInt() and test if
  // that found number is greater than zero:
  if (number && parseInt(number[1], 10) > 0) {

    // if both the above are true, then here we
    // use the Element.classList API to add the
    // 'hasAbsences' class to the current <td>
    // element:
    cell.classList.add('hasAbsences');
  }
});
```

And specify the `.hasAbsences` class in the CSS.

```js
var tableCells = document.querySelectorAll('table td'),


  tableCellsArray = Array.from(tableCells),
  reg = /\/(\d+)/,
  number;
tableCellsArray.forEach(function(cell) {
  number = cell.textContent.match(reg);
  if (number && parseInt(number[1], 10) > 0) {
    cell.classList.add('hasAbsences');
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
}
td.hasAbsences {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1/2</td>
      <td>2/0</td>
      <td>3/0</td>
      <td>4/0</td>
      <td>5/1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1/0</td>
      <td>2/0</td>
      <td>3/-1</td>
      <td>4/0</td>
      <td>5/0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1/0</td>
      <td>2/2</td>
      <td>3/0</td>
      <td>4/6</td>
      <td>5/0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/m76urr68/).

Answer (score 0):

Does it only contains numbers?

One way to do it is with parseInt the innerHTML:

```js
var cells = document.getElementById("test").getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
 if (parseInt(cells[i].innerHTML.split('/')[1]) > 0) {
     cells[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }   
}
```

```html
<table id="test">
 <tr>
  <td>
   0/0
  </td>
  <td>
   1/0
  </td>
  <td>
   2/1
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

EDIT: Got the question wrong edited..

Comment: Daniel H, yes cells all contains numbers in the same format, with no exceptions - eg   2/0,  3/0,  5/1, 6/2

David Thomas, thanks for your advice on editing.

Comment: Daniel H, that solution worked perfectly. Many thanks!

Jim

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this one.

```
var cells = document.getElementById("test").getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
if (cells[i].innerHTML.indexOf('/') > -1 && parseInt(cells[i].innerHTML.split("/")[1]) > 0) {
    cells[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }   
}
```

Comment: saddam_msp , that solution worked as well. Many thanks!

Thanks to all who responded. 

Jim